# jQuery and @Html.TextBoxfor()

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I currently have the following code:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(IList<LocalPageModel> postPages,
          IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in files)
                {
                    if ((file != null) && (file.ContentLength > 0))
                    {
                        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/"),
                          fileName);
                        file.SaveAs(path);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ManagePagesModel mod = new ManagePagesModel
                {
                    PostPages = postPages
                };

                return View("Index", mod);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

In my view, I have a JavaScript button which will add a `div` so that the user can post another page such as:

```
$("#add-page").click(function () {
    $("#page").append('<div id="page"> @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.PostPages[0].Title) </div>');
});
```

How do I make it so that when the user clicks on the JavaScript button, the new text will be appended to the page **and** `u.PostPages[x]` will be incremented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it all on the client (no AJAX), maybe don't use the MVC helpers at all, and do it manually instead - you know the HTML that will be rendered, so just do that:

```
var i = 0;
$("#add-page").click(function () {
   $("#page").append('<input type="text" name="PostPages[' + (i++) + '].Title">');
});
```

Maybe clean the code up a bit so the quotes don't get too confusing, but you get the idea...

Answer (score 0):

To increment u.PostPages[x] you may use following code:

```
<script>

var i = 0;

$("#add-page").click(function () {
    i++
    $("#page").append('<div id="page"> @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.PostPages['+i+'].Title') </div>');
});

</script>
```

Here is small working example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gubal/eVfGa/)

Comment: I can't see this working. I would say it will throw an exception on page load, as you're passing a javascript variable to the serversude html helper.

Comment: @Stephen I've edited my answer a bit. In that moment it's not a html.helper yet. It's just a text that you append in div.

Comment: I'm not gonna argue with you and leave it at this: if it's just text you append in the div and not a Html helper, you'll just get divs filled with `@Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.PostPages[whatevercounter i is at].Title')`, if the string termination was correct, which it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't past your view, but I assume you have the following at the top:

```
@model = ManagePagesModel
```

If that's the case, you can then use the following @foreach to loop through the page models:

```
$("#add-page).click(function() {
@foreach(var pageModel in Model.PostPages){
 $("#page").append('<div id="page"> @Html.TextBoxFor(u => pageModel.Title) </div>');
});
```